# Error not clear in query in component, how to track the query which fails

Tags: extensions, joomla-4

In my component i have an error showed in top of the page coming from a query which has failed :

Syntax error near to '' at line 3

Is-there a way to track the place and the query which fails in this case ?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned all the way up?  Anything in the error logs?  https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/how-to-turn-your-error-reporting-to-maximum/ https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/warnings/

Comment: yes, debug mode is enabled in Joomla! configuration panel, i have nothing in the logs

Comment: With debug mode set on and the logs set to almost everything, you should get something in the logs.  However, without a little more explanation of what you were trying to do at the time of the error, such as Admin/Site side, multiple list of item view etc, not much more to add.  Although a quick thought, do you have a second end quote anywhere in your queries? (models or helper)

Comment: I finally found the place where it happens, now the issue is fixed